# How do you make a car move in the direction it is facing? (Using python and turtle graphics)

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I am building a simple python game using turtle graphics that is a car that goes around a track. I have built the track and the car, and I know how to turn the car in different directions, but I don't know how to get the car to move in the specific direction that it is facing. Does anyone have any ideas? This is what I have so far:

```
    import turtle

    #Screen
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.title('Car')
    wn.bgcolor('black')
    wn.setup(width=1200, height=1200)
    wn.tracer(0)

    #Track
    track = turtle.Turtle()
    track.color('white')
    track.speed(0)
    track.penup()
    track.goto(-550, 0)
    track.pendown()
    track.goto(-550, 300)
    track.goto(-100,370)
    track.goto(100, 210)
    track.goto(300, 380)
    track.goto(580, 100)
    track.goto(570, -300)
    track.goto(300, -370)
    track.goto(0, -250)
    track.goto(-300, -200)
    track.goto(-570, -250)
    track.goto(-550, 0)
    track.hideturtle()

    #Track 2
    track2 = turtle.Turtle()
    track2.color('white')
    track2.speed(0)
    track2.penup()
    track2.goto(-450, 0)
    track2.pendown()
    track2.goto(-450, 230)
    track2.goto(-150, 250)
    track2.goto(100, 100)
    track2.goto(300, 200)
    track2.goto(460, 100)
    track2.goto(450, -220)
    track2.goto(300, -250)
    track2.goto(0, -130)
    track2.goto(-300, -100)
    track2.goto(-450, 0)
    track2.hideturtle()

    #Start line
    line = turtle.Turtle()
    line.color('white')
    line.speed(0)
    line.penup()
    line.goto(-550, 0)
    line.pendown()
    line.goto(-450,0)
    line.hideturtle()

    #Car
    car = turtle.Turtle()
    car.color('red')
    car.speed(0)
    car.penup() 
    car.shape('square')
    car.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=2)
    car.goto(-500, 0)
    car.setheading(90)



    #Move car
    def turn_right():
        car.right(20)
    def turn_left():
        car.left(20)


    #Key Bindings
    wn.listen()
    wn.onkey(turn_right, 'd')
    wn.onkey(turn_left, 'a')


    while True:
        wn.update()

    turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is to change this:

```
while True:
    wn.update()
```

to instead be:

```
while True:
    car.forward(1)
    wn.update()
```

and you'll find your car moves foward and requires you to steer it to stay on the track.  The more complicated answer is that `while True:` has no business in an event-driven environment like turtle and that what you need is a timer event:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop

# Move car
def turn_right():
    car.right(20)

def turn_left():
    car.left(20)

def move():
    car.forward(1)
    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(move, 25)

# Screen
screen = Screen()
screen.title('Car')
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.setup(width=1200, height=1200)
screen.tracer(0)

# Track
track = Turtle()
track.hideturtle()
track.color('white')

track.penup()
track.goto(-550, 0)
track.pendown()

track.goto(-550, 300)
track.goto(-100, 370)
track.goto(100, 210)
track.goto(300, 380)
track.goto(580, 100)
track.goto(570, -300)
track.goto(300, -370)
track.goto(0, -250)
track.goto(-300, -200)
track.goto(-570, -250)
track.goto(-550, 0)

track.penup()
track.goto(-450, 0)
track.pendown()

track.goto(-450, 230)
track.goto(-150, 250)
track.goto(100, 100)
track.goto(300, 200)
track.goto(460, 100)
track.goto(450, -220)
track.goto(300, -250)
track.goto(0, -130)
track.goto(-300, -100)
track.goto(-450, 0)

# Start line
line = Turtle()
line.hideturtle()
line.color('white')

line.penup()
line.setx(-550)
line.pendown()
line.setx(-450)

# Car
car = Turtle()
car.shape('square')
car.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=2)
car.color('red')
car.setheading(90)
car.penup()
car.setx(-500)

# Key Bindings
screen.onkey(turn_right, 'd')
screen.onkey(turn_left, 'a')
screen.listen()

move()

mainloop()
```